# How to modify default footer links in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, footer-links

Magento 2.1.9

I want to change the privacy policy link text, it's located at,

```
Privacy-cookie: magento2/vendor/magento/module-cms/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

If I edit it there, it works fine. However we all know you don't edit core files, so I copied the file to my custom theme,

**magento2/app/design/frontend/custom_vendor/custom_theme/module-cms/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

However the changes aren't being loaded. Where is the correct place in my custom theme to put `default.xml` so that it overrides the magento default one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong directory name. rename `module-cms` to `Magento_Cms`. Also, you don't need to place it into `view/frontend`. So that the correct path is:

> magento2/app/design/frontend/custom_vendor/custom_theme/Magento_Cms/layout/default.xml

Comment: Just double checked, path is correct in my post on a fresh install of magento 2.1.9      vendor/magento/module-cms/view/frontend/layout/default.xml